# Update Product programmatically - Invalid method Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute::isScopeGlobal

Tags: magento2, product, repository

I have a quite simple piece of code (reduced it to that):

```
try {
    $newProduct = $this->productRepository->get($productData['sku']);
    echo 'Loaded.' . PHP_EOL;
    $savedProduct = $this->productRepository->save($newProduct);
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
    echo 'Saving failed; product does not exist. ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    // $newProduct = $this->productInterfaceFactory->create();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Just some other problem: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

and it outputs this:

```
Loaded.
Just some other problem: Invalid method Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute::isScopeGlobal
```

... I have no clue why this could happen. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you found the solution? I'm experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took us some ours of investigation... But we finally found the cause:

Integer attributes of products were not saved at all, while all other attributes were properly propagated. Why? - Someone had changed the value_id column of our catalog_product_entity_int table to BIGINT via a setup script, but forgotten to explicitly set the auto_increment attribute:

[image: auto increment value missing]

To fix it, I added the *auto increment* attribute to the _auto_increment_ column:

[image]

I think, there might be many other causes for this error message; but this was it for us here.